# Is there a way of setting a path for scripts?

Tags: .net, ajax

I'm using a number of ajax utils that generate scripts. ModalPopupExtender being one of them.

I've set up a static subdomain for all my css/js/images etc and I simply prepend the path.

What i'd like to do is do the same with the ajax scripts - is this possible? In effect I'm wanting to bundle the scripts to me own CDN.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's some documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.scripts.aspx (.Net 4.0 and above)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.scriptpath(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.scriptpath%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (.Net 3.5)

The script files are at:

(see comment, not enough rep...)

You should then be able to change the script path for each script resource and away you go.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNAjax35.ashx (3.5)

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNAjax4.ashx (4.0)

Comment: This eems to be for generic scripts. I'm looking as to how I can create my own scripts upload them to my server and reference them absolutely rather than relatively.

Comment: You should be able to override the default scripts and replace them with the paths to your own scripts. I can't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to use a full URL instead of a relative one.